# Emacs custom major mode with multiple comment types

Tags: major-mode, comment

I'm trying to write my first (very simple) major mode for Emacs. My goal is to have multiple comment types, but I can't find a way to implement this. Basically, I want my major mode to make highlighted comments as follows

- line that comes after `#`, exactly like in Python
- line that comes after `!`, same as above, but with a different color. Also, I want to be able to add a `#` comment at the end of this line.
- a code block starting with `%` and ending in `end`, again with a different color

So far, I have the following in my .el file:

```
(defvar my-mode-hook nil)

(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap)))
    map)

(defvar my-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; comment style: "# ..."
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# "<" st)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\n ">" st)
    (setq comment-start "# ") 
    (setq comment-end "")
    st))

(defvar my-highlights
  '(("!\\|" . font-lock-function-name-face)
    ("!\\([^<]+?\\)\n" . (1 font-lock-function-name-face))))

(define-derived-mode my-mode prog-mode "my-mode"
  (interactive)
  ;; (kill-all-local-variables)
  (use-local-map my-mode-map)
  (set-syntax-table my-mode-syntax-table)
  (setq font-lock-defaults (list nil nil))
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults) '(my-highlights))
  ;; (set (make-local-variable 'indent-line-function) 'my-indent-line)
  (setq major-mode 'my-mode)
  (setq mode-name "MY MODE")

  (run-hooks 'my-mode-hook))
```

This works somewhat for `#` and `!`, but the text highlight for `!` comments does not work if I put a `#` at the end of the line. Also, it only works after I hit enter at the end of the line, not straight after the `!` as I write.

[image: An example]

Answer (score 3):

Here are some tips to get you started:

- The `(setq comment-start/end ..)` needs to be within the `define-derived-mode`, not within that `defvar` of `my-mode-syntax-table` (otherwise it just sets the comment style in the buffer that happens to be current when your code loaded, rather than in all the buffers that use your mode).
- You wan to add `(modify-syntax-entry ?! "<" st)` since `!` also starts a single-line comment.
- To change the color of comments depending on the char that introduces it, you'll want to set `font-lock-syntactic-face-function`.
- You want to add `(modify-syntax-entry ?% "< b" st)` since `%` starts a comment, but one that's ended with something else than `\n` so it needs to use another style (alternatively, you could mark `%`, `\n`, and `!` as style `b` and use the "default" style for this one).  To mark `end` as being the matching comment ender, you'll have to use `syntax-propertize-function`, e.g.

  ```
  (setq-local syntax-propertize-local
              (syntax-propertize-rules
               ("e\\(n\\)\\(d\\)" (1 "w 3b") (2 "w 4b"))))
  ```

  note that the exact rule to use will depend on whether the `end` in `bending` also ends the comment (for example).
- You don't need `(interactive)`, `(use-local-map my-mode-map`), `(set-syntax-table my-mode-syntax-table)`, `(setq major-mode 'my-mode)`, `(setq mode-name "MY MODE")`, nor `(run-hooks 'my-mode-hook)` since `define-derived-mode` already does that (tho you might then like to change `"my-mode"` to `"MY MODE"`).
- Your code sets `font-lock-defaults` twice (and not to the same value).